# のりまきみたいにくるまればふかふかふとんになるんだもん。

Tags: grammar, reading-comprehension

In a Japanese children's book I read:

```
のりまきみたいに　くるまれば　ふかふか　ふとんに　なるんだもん。
```

For the sake of analysis, I looked up the kanjis (correct me if they're wrong):

```
海苔巻きみたいに包まればふかふか布団になるんだもん。
```

From the context, it should mean something along the lines, "I can wrap it up like a Nori roll and it becomes a soft mattress."

However, two things are unclear to me: First, is くるまれば really a form of 包まる? If so, what verb form is it? jisho.org does not have it in its list of inflections. What does this form mean, when do I use it?

Second, what does もん mean? Is it a shortened form of 物? How does this word alter the sentence?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 「のりまきみたいに　くるまれば　ふかふか　ふとんに　なるんだもん」

Since more context was definitely needed to discuss this sentence, I searched and found out [here](https://ameblo.jp/newsongs/entry-10005844616.html) that this is about a ***girl with extremely long black hair***.  That piece of information is of much importance and the preceding sentence is:

> 「そとにだって　ねられるの。」

Using kanji, we have:

> 「外にだって寝られるの。のり巻きみたいに包まればふかふかふとんにになるんだもん。」

The 「もん/もの」 should be written in **kana** because it is a sentence-ending particle meaning roughly "because".

> First, is くるまれば really a form of 包まる? If so, what verb form is it?

「包まれば」 is simply the conditional form of 「包まる」 meaning "**if I am wrapped up**".  It is used when talking hypothetically about getting wrapped up in something.  In this case, that something is the girl's own long hair.  See what I mean when I say I could never have answered this (seemingly simple) question without more context?

My own TL:

> "I can even sleep outside.  (That's because) if I am wrapped up in (my long hair) like a sushi roll, it turns into a fluffy futon."

Comment: Yes, it's exactly that story. ありがとうございました。